# what's meaning of Ant exec Result:128

Tags: ant, exec

my ant was stoped when execute `"<exec excultable="c:\myExe.exe"/>"`,the result code is just `"<message priority="error"><![CDATA[Result: 128]]></message>"`.I don't know what's meaning of that.

I've tried to search some info like: error code 128---no such exe file,but I havn't.
some one could help me to explain what's the meaning?

Thanks

```
Oh sorry.
More info:

<macrodef name="gtest-layer-macro">
    <attribute name="execfile"/>
    <attribute name="layerpath" default=""/>
    <attribute name="outputDir" default="${basedir}/${reports}/gtest"/>
    <attribute name="reportfile" default="@{outputDir}/gtest_report.xml"/>
    <sequential>
        <check-layer-path layerpath="@{layerpath}"/>
        <if>
            <and>
                <length string="@{execfile}" when="gt" length="0" trim="true"/>
                <available file="@{execfile}"/>
            </and>
            <then>
                <var name="##report.dir##" unset="true"/>
                <dirname property="##report.dir##" file="@{reportfile}"/>
                <mkdir dir="${##report.dir##}"/>
                <exec executable="@{execfile}">
                    <arg value="--gtest_output=&quot;xml:@{reportfile}&quot;"/>
                </exec>
            </then>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

When I run the `<exec>`, there’s "error Result:128".

The “@{execfile}” is a gtest.exe file(a exe file to test a module),it could run correctly when I double-click it,it could print the unit test result in the console;Run in the CMD with “--gtest_output="xml:@{reportfile}"” is also could print the unit test result in the console,and output a unit test report(a .xml file).And I have changed another .exe instead of the “gtest.exe”,it’s right too.
So,I don’t know where I’m wrong.

Comment: Not enough information to troubleshoot this problem.... What happens when you run the command "C:\myExe.exe" from the command-line? In other words when you run it outside of ANT?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor is right, you are not giving us a lot of information here.

Answer (score 0):

An `[exec] Result:128` is a process that can't be found/doesn't exist. At least this is what I've found out from my Ant target to kill any remaining processes at the end of certain tests. I get that result when the process I want to kill isn't running. My build log output looks like this;

```
[shutdown.server] exec
    [13:45:33][exec] ERROR: The process "firefox.exe" not found.
    [13:45:34][exec] Result: 128
```

So if that result is from the execution of your `.exe` then I'd check the path to ensure the exe is available.